# How can I show all errors in Twig?

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, twig

I create a form in Symfony 5 and when validation is wrong I want if errors are true, show all errors in one  like this:
Errors:

- error 1
- error 2
- error 3
  ...

I use :

```
{% if form_errors(form)|length %}
     <div>Errors:</div>
     {{ form_errors(form) }}
{% endif %}
```

but not work.

How can I do this in Twig?

Comment: `|lenght` should be `|length` unless you have defined a custom filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in your codes:

```
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
<div>Errors:</div>
    <ul>
        {% for error in form.vars.errors.form.getErrors(true) %}
            <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You display all errors using below

```
{# 
If the form is not valid then :
Note: in this case the form variable is : form
 #}
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
<ul>
    {# Loop through every form item #}
    {% for child in form.children %}
        {# Display the errors of the form item #}
        {%for error in child.vars.errors%}
            <li>{{error.message}}</li>
        {%endfor%}
    {%endfor%}
</ul>
{%endif%}
```

Comment: Thank you but show this error: Key "errors" for array with keys "value, attr, form, id, name, full_name, disabled, label, label_format, label_html, multipart, block_prefixes, unique_block_prefix, row_attr, translation_domain, label_translation_parameters, attr_translation_parameters, cache_key, clicked" does not exist.